# Openpyxl corrupted my excel file and now it is lost?

Tags: openpyxl

I have been using openpyxl to write some data to an already existing Excel file and I was finding it quite user friendly and easy. 
However, things started to go wrong yesterday.

The excel file that my python code loads has some titles in A2, B2, C2, e.t.c. and the code prints some data below each column.

During the afternoon I ran the code (I have been running it a lot and doing lots of trial and error) and it worked exactly as hoped except a few columns in various sheets of the Excel file had mysteriously disappeared.  This was because some columns (mostly where there was data) had been minimized to 0 pixels wide for some reason, and once I had expanded the column wider again, everything was as it should be.  One of the sheets that had had columns being minimized was not being touched by the code.  Not sure if this is relevant but found it strange so thought I'd add it anyway.

Then during the evening, I ran the code again trialing a couple of new functions I had added.  It looked to be working fine, but when it got to the .save() command at the end it threw out all these errors:

---

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "whoscored_scraper.py", line 239, in <module>
wb2.save("WhoscoredDatabase.xlsx")
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", l
ine 296, in save
save_workbook(self, filename)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 1
91, in save_workbook
writer.save(filename, as_template=as_template)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 1
74, in save
self.write_data(archive, as_template=as_template)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 8
5, in write_data
self._write_worksheets(archive)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 1
11, in _write_worksheets
write_worksheet(sheet, self.workbook.shared_strings,
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\writer\worksheet.py", li
ne 299, in write_worksheet
xf.write(comments)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\contextlib.py", line 24, in _
_exit__
self.gen.next()
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\xml\xmlfile.py", line 51
, in element
self._write_element(el)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\openpyxl\xml\xmlfile.py", line 78
, in _write_element
xml = tostring(element)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 1126, in tostring
ElementTree(element).write(file, encoding, method=method)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 820, in write
serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 939, in _serialize_xml
_serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 939, in _serialize_xml
_serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 932, in _serialize_xml
v = _escape_attrib(v, encoding)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 1092, in _escape_attrib
_raise_serialization_error(text)
File "C:\Users\SamH\Documents\Betting\Python\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", li
ne 1052, in _raise_serialization_error
"cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize 7L (type long)
```

---

My code is quite long, so below are some of the lines that involve openpyxl:

---

```
from openpyxl import workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('filename.xlsx')
ws = wb2["Shots_and_Goals"]
ws4 = wb2["Assorted"]
ws2 = wb2["On_Target"]

def HomeTeam(string):
    HomeTeam_cell = “c” + str(3)
    ws[str(HomeTeam_cell)] = Home_Team   #Home_Team is some variable

def Home_Shot_Minutes(string):
   for num in range (0, 10):
       cell = column_titles[num+10] + str(3)] #column_titles is just a list
       ws[str(cell)] = int(shot_count_for_that_minute)    #shot_count_for_that_minute is variable defined above

HomeTeam(data)
Home_Shot_Minutes(data)
Wb2.save(“filename.xlsx”)
```

---

There’s a lot more lines of code that are basically the same as those listed above.  Everything had been working correctly up until this point.

When I try and open the new saved file, it says Excel has found unreadable content 
When I say I want to recover the unreadable content, my new excel file is totally blank apart from the sheet names.

I know it was a stupid decision to not save the file as a different filename as then it would mean I don’t have to remake my entire Excel file!

Does anyone understand what went wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the data is lost because the original file was overwritten.

Please submit a bug report with the original file so that we can investigate. It's clear where the error is coming from but we need the original data to reproduce it.

In the meantime I suspect the problem is unlikely to happen if you install lxml.

Comment: hi, sorry to be dense but I'm not sure how to produce a bug report with the original file?  This is the repair of the excel file:            

<removedRecord>Removed Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)</removedRecord>

Comment: Go to the bug tracker: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/overview 
The repair notice from Excel is no help, unfortunately. The corrupt file won't be much help either because it's missing the list of text items.

Comment: ok thanks, the corrupted file seemed to be a one off and I haven't been able to repeat the error but my code still seems to be setting loads of column to 0 width and I have to expand them again.  Any idea why this might be happening?